# Running Google Picker with offline access oAuth token

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-picker

**What I am doing:**

I am integrating [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker) on my page. This will allow users to select files from their Google Drive to be used in the web app. In the app, people in a group share a common google drive (i.e. they all can select files from account example@email.com) which was created by group admin by his email address. When the admin signs-up for the account we do OAuth and get `access_token` with `refresh_token` against our app on google (with offline access enabled). I plan to use the `access_token` and `refresh-token` of the admin, on other group user's account when they try to use picker to select files.

**What I have done:**

I have integrated the Google Picker successfully in my app using the basic code provided in [docs](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#gdata). Then to achieve what I wanted, I removed following code from the example code:

```
gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
```

and

```
function onAuthApiLoad() {
  window.gapi.auth.authorize(
    {
      'client_id': clientId,
      'scope': scope,
      'immediate': false
    },
    handleAuthResult);
}
```

and

```
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
    createPicker();
  }
}
```

and instead of `.setOAuthToken(oauthToken)` I pass refreshed access_token directly as string (I get that from my server with an ajax call).

```
.setOAuthToken("<access_token>")
```

But every time I call `picker.setVisible(true);` I get a screen in an iframe saying **In order to select an item from your online storage, please sign in.**

[image]

**Problem:**

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @ot954 I did, but that was 3 years ago. I'll dig into my repository to see if I still have that code.

Comment: The only way I could find out is by using App script. But still I am not pretty much sure how to serve html from google app script. In my case I have integrated user's drive with my application. Once integration is done, google picker should never show this sign in.

Comment: @ot954 did you get anywhere with this? Getting same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try to add [`sign in listener`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners). Listeners provide a way to automatically respond to changes in the current user's Sign-In session. For example, after your startup method initializes the Google Sign-In auth2 object, you can set up listeners to respond to events like auth2.isSignedIn state changes, or changes in auth2.currentUser.

[Validating the token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken) might be a possibility before using the token each time but that might add a lot of extra overhead for a rare use-case each time we load the picker and when calling the API endpoints with a token after the re-authentication issue, there was no key about the token being invalid. You can validate a token by making a web service request to an endpoint on the Google Authorization Server and performing a string match on the results of that web service request.